# docker push of a 1.2 GB image

Tags: docker

I went through the list of debian packages in bio-ngs (http://blends.debian.org/med/tasks/bio-ngs) and tried to install them in a docker container based on Ubuntu Precise.

I did it manually by doing a `sudo docker run [...] /bin/bash` and doing `apt-get install` on each package.

I then tried to `docker commit` and `docker push` the container with everything in bio-ngs, and it tried to upload the 1.215 GB of data in one go.

A few seconds after starting the process, it failed with this error:

```
4160cce5fef0: Pushing [=>                                                 ] 24.42 MB/1.215 GB 1h6m34s

2014/02/19 17:07:37 Failed to upload layer: Put https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/images/4160cce5fef01ae777b856c15a42e0a632021d1891c33f29018024e35aed60be/layer: write tcp 54.224.119.89:443: broken pipe
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this again since it failed? I know that the registry was down and/or having errors recently. The error `write tcp 54.224.119.89:443: broken pipe` looks connection related.

Comment: I retried it and the server accepted my big fat container this time: `Pushing tags for rev [4160cce5fef0] on {https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/avilella/bio-ngs/tags/latest}`.

Comment: Is that actually still the case?